# Parsing code send from Web service in client application

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, duplex

I'm looking to see if there's a method of parsing code from a web service in a client application.

The reason being is that the code I'm calling from the client can change every couple of weeks and I don't want to keep updating the client all the time. If I can call a service which updates the definition of the code I need to call then before making the call I can check to see if the code has updated before making the call. It's like an auto update mechanism but without having the fully update the client application.

A little context, it's a form post to a website and the website may change the login method or the additional calls I need to make.

The API is a WCF application running in duplex so the server calls the client to make the calls it needs. It need to run on the client as it needs to come from the client's IP address else I would do it all on the server.

I don't know how much more I can add to this, is it remotely possible does anyone know?

I know in asp.net you can write user controls which are parsed at runtime, is there something similar for a forms app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand, you want to parse/compile C# code. Here's a tutorial (utilizing the `CSharpCodeProvider` and `CompilerResults` classes):

http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/715891/Compiling-Csharp-Code-at-Runtime

Comment: That looks to be exactly what I am looking for.

I'm going to do some light testing with this and I'll update the question if it's solved the answer.

Thanks